# How to split video files upon detected change in speakers? (ie. different file for different speaker)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I have an audio file that have 2 speakers . Audio file has conversation between them. I want to split that file in 2 parts. One part should have conversation of Person A and other should have conversation of Person B.

I have tried to split on silent but it does not work. I have tried by using below commands.

"ffmpeg -i input.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-30dB:d=0.2 -f null - 2> vol.txt"

But my audio file has some random pauses as well. So this solution is not working. i need to differentiate between speakers. 
 Any suggestion to do this?

Comment: "I have tried to split on silent but it does not work." — what exactly have you tried, and in what sense did it not work? Please clarify.

Comment: I ve tried below commands to break the audio on silent
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-30dB:d=0.2 -f null - 2> vol.txt

But my audio file has some random pauses as well. So this solution is not working. i need to differentiate between speakers.

Comment: Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.